# What does error : "prefix" is not set and error: "prefix" not found means?

Tags: boot

Before I disabled the ACPI (because it is not supported by Ubuntu) Ubuntu can't boot (obviously!)

At that time when I boot Ubuntu, I always get these 2 messages.  After 1 of those message shows, nothing shows up.

```
error: "prefix" is not set 
error: "prefix" not found
```

Although my problem is solved, I just want to know what these 2 messages mean in general, like what makes GRUB show this message.  Espically the "prefix" part.

Comment: Impossible without further context. Include surrounding lines or take a photo of the screen and post it.

Comment: No, that's the only line that appears.  And the problem is fixed now so it is impossible to post any screenshot :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [bcbc](https://launchpad.net/~bcbc) (who is [very](https://answers.launchpad.net/~bcbc/+answeredquestions) [knowledgeable](https://askubuntu.com/users/14916/bcbc?tab=answers) about Wubi):

> The message about the 'prefix not being set' is innocuous (happens on every 11.04 wubi install on every boot).

**Source:** Answer #2 to [this question on Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/wubi/+question/171739).

That is to say that this error message always occurs, even on Wubi systems that are working properly. **If you're experiencing (or used to experience) an actual problem, it's actually unrelated to that message.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  But what does the "prefix" mean?